# How to do Loose Character Search in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem with search, currently running on SQL Server 2008. I have the names like below (in a table with thousands of records like this). I want to search the sub string of string with the starting letter.

[Names]

**E**yvind **J**ohnson

**E**mily **J**ohn

**J**ohannes **V**ilhelm **J**ensen

**J**ohn **G**alsworthy

**J**ohn **S**teinbeck

- If I am searching for "**E J**", it should return "Eyvind Johnson" and "Emily John"
- If I am searching for "**J V J**", it should return "Johannes Vilhelm Jensen"
- If I am searching for "**J S**", it should return "John Steinbeck"

What's the best practice for handling these sorts of search queries?

Comment: The best option here probably is to look into full text search.  SQL Server has poor native regex support, which would be another option in other databases.